# Derivative + Exponet + Power Rule Question: $\frac{x}{20}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$\frac{x}{20}$

If I transfer the 20 to the denominator how what is its relation to the variable x? is it $\frac{20^{-1}x}{1}$ or is it $\frac{x20^{-1}}{1}$

With that in mind, how do I go about finding the derivative?

Can I use the power rule?

Comment: $20^{-1}$ is simply $\frac{1}{20}$, so it is a constant and the derivative of $\frac{x}{20}$ is $\frac{1}{20}=20^{-1}$.

Comment: So I can't preform the product rule when I transfer it to the numerator?

Comment: See my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in my comment:

$20^{-1}=\dfrac{1}{20}$ is a constant, so, obviusly by commutativity, we have $20^{-1}x=x20^{-1}$ and the derivative is $(20^{-1}x)'=20^{-1}=\dfrac{1}{20}$

You can use the product rule, if you want, but since $20^{-1}$ is a constant, its derivative is $0$ so you have $$(20^{-1}x)'=(20^{-1})'x+20^{-1}=0\cdot x+20^{-1}=20^{-1}$$

Comment: Thank you for the clarity.